# ¿Cómo poner un gif animado en tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Soy nuevo en el mundo de tkinter, y he estado buscando hace unas horas y no encuentro una solución, lo único que he encontrado es `configure(image=nextframe)` y que lo coloque por frames, solo que no se como hacerlo

Answer (score 2):

En la mayoría de los casos para que el gif se visualice bien es necesario utilizar un canvas, así que te dejo este ejemplo:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

framesNum = 160 # Numero de frames que tiene el gif, si no lo conoces ir haciendo tentativos.
archivo = "imagen.gif"

# Lista de todas las imagenes del gif
frames = [PhotoImage(file=archivo, format='gif -index %i' %(i)) for i in range(framesNum)]

def update(ind):
    """ Actualiza la imagen gif """
    frame = frames[ind]
    ind += 1
    if ind == framesNum:
        ind = 0
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=frame, anchor=NW)
    root.after(20, update, ind) # Numero que regula la velocidad del gif

canvas = Canvas(width=300, height=100) # Modificar segun el tamaño de la imagen

canvas.pack()
root.after(0, update, 0)
root.mainloop()
```

> El uso de canvas es sin duda tu mejor opción debido a que por defecto su color de fondo es transparente y permite la sobreposición de las diferentes imágenes.

Como no sé si para ti es imprescindible utilizar un label te dejo este otro ejemplo:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

framesNum = 160 # Numero de frames que tiene el gif
archivo = "imagen.gif"

# Lista de todas las imagenes del gif
frames = [PhotoImage(file=archivo, format='gif -index %i' %(i)) for i in range(framesNum)]

def update(ind):
    """ Actualiza la imagen gif """
    frame = frames[ind]
    ind += 1
    if ind == framesNum:
        ind = 0
    label.configure(image=frame)
    root.after(100, update, ind) # Numero que regula la velocidad del gif

label = Label(root)
label.pack()
root.after(0, update, 0)
root.mainloop()
```

> No recomiendo para nada que utilices label's para esto ya que el label tiene un color de fondo blanco que no puede ponerse transparente y evitará la correcta visualización del gif. Este último ejemplo proviene de esta [referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28518072/play-animations-in-gif-with-tkinter).